# PHP Script Confusing GEO Lite DB

Tags: php, mysql, ip

i need to get the country name from user ip. as far far i know it can be done by two ways:

1. call third party api (but that might be slow)
2. use own database

so, i download IP database from following site:
    http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

and create a table in my DB, then user php script to get the ip and then country

but it is not working for my own country :(

but works while i check on my vps

currently my ip is : 180.211.255.204

So, i think may be that db is not updated.

but when i try same ip with that website demo test it works fine:

https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo

then where is the issue? is the db is different or my code is faulty?

i am damn confused :(

here is the code i use to get country:

```
$strSQL="SELECT `country_name` FROM `IPCountry` WHERE INET_ATON('" . $strIP . "') BETWEEN ip_range_start_int AND ip_range_end_int LIMIT 1";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the latest version of GeoLite database?

Comment: @MichaelC. yes sir, i have downloaded the db just before the day i post this question. :(

Answer (score 0):

If other IPs return a correct result your query/code is probably okay.

Here are a few things to consider/try:
1. Maxmind itself (on there demo) probably does not use the lite version of their own database so the results you get there can be more accurate.

2. You can also try the GeoLite2 Database which you can finde here.
3. Instead of doing sql-queries you should try the php-extension provided by maxmind as it is probably a lot faster. Instructions on how to use this extension can be found here: http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-php/

Btw. I myself use geolite2 database and it returns "Bangladesh" as country for the IP you provided. (See: http://geoip.nekudo.com/api/180.211.255.204)

Comment: sir, did you used the same database on your server like i did? if so, can you share the code you use, i think either you didn't use the same db than me or same code that i used? any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: The sourcecode is availabe here: https://github.com/nekudo/shiny_geoip
I use the GeoLite2 City database which is available here: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/